# q node.js, callback after mongoose's "post"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, q

I have this source code:

```
UserSchema.post('save', function (next) {
    doSomethingAsync(function(){
        next()
    });
});

myFunc = function(user){
     Q.ninvoke(user, 'save').then(function(){
          doThisAtTheEnd()
     });
}
```

But then is called before "doSomethingAsync" calls is callback. How is it possible?!
How can I call "then" after all the saving stuff is done?

Thanks very much

EDIT:
the two functions are in different files, no way nor intention to use a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for Q.ninvoke: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qninvokeobject-methodname-args

> Calls a Node.js-style method with the given variadic arguments,
>   returning a promise that is fulfilled if the method calls back with a
>   result, or rejected if it calls back with an error (or throws one
>   synchronously)

And looking at mongoose schema.post('save'): http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

> post middleware are executed after the hooked method and all of its
>   pre middleware have completed. post middleware do not directly receive
>   flow control, e.g. no next or done callbacks are passed to it. post
>   hooks are a way to register traditional event listeners for these
>   methods.

Which means that there is no next for you to call in the doSomethingAsync. Probably something is internally calling back into the ninvoke.

How about deferers? You could generate a deferer and resolve it. i.e.:

```
var saveDeferer = Q.defer();

UserSchema.post('save', function (next) {
    doSomethingAsync(function(){
        saveDeferer.resolve();
    });
});

saveDeferer.promise.then( function() { doSomething(); } );
```

---

Update after the question edit:

It seems to me that you are trying to use `schema.post('save', ...` as an eventbus that carries flow variables around. I don't see any direct answer to your edit, other than either use a custom event bus, or do some refactoring so that you can pass the promise references around.